# MediaPlayer's prepareAsync seems to stop working on Android 9

Tags: android, version, android-mediaplayer

I'm using `MediaPlayer` to play mp3 files (url) and everything is working great.

```
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);

prepareAsync();

mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(onPreparedListener);
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);
```

But when tested on Android Pie (9), it just stops working...

I checked the logging but the error is kind of not very clear :

> E/MediaPlayer_JAVA: Error (1,-2147483648)

Comment: what does "it just stops working" even mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while struggling with the issue, I decided to change to `ExoPlayer` and the problem persits, but the error was clearer, and here is the solution : [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)